# Django CeleryTask return GeoDataFrames leads to TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, celery, task, geopandas

I am trying to build a web app in which I make use of celery to tackle a long running process. I need to pass to the view that called the task a couple of GeoDataFrame and an epsg projection value.

```
return {'Working_area_final': Working_area_final.to_json(), 'PoI_buffer_small': PoI_buffer_small.to_json(), 'Streets_gdf': Streets_gdf.to_json(), 'PoI_buffer_BIG_exp': PoI_buffer_BIG_exp.to_json(), 'projection': str(proj.to_epsg(), 'ip': ip.to_json()}
```

The problem occurs here. I get 'TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable'. I can tell that before this command I manage to successfully print to console everything that has to be passed as result.

EDIT
Found out that one of the GeoDataFrame failed the conversion to json. It is a Geodataframe retrieved from a graph of osmnx package. Now the question switch to: Why does this occur only on this Geodataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Have created a MWE with what you describe.   It does not fail (as expected) when serialised as JSON (actually GEOJSON).  I suggest that you provide more details on

1. how you are using **osmnx**
2. how you are doing CRS projection

```
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox

cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
p = cities.loc[cities["name"].eq("Vaduz"), "geometry"].values[0].coords[0]

G = ox.graph_from_point(p[::-1], simplify=True)
# get the edges, these will be linestrings
gdf = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=True)[1]

gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs()).to_json()
```

Comment: In fact my piece of code is quite similar to yours and works outside the django app. I found a workaround for my problem. I converted the GDF to dict using the __geo_interface__ method and then created a new GDF out of that. It's not an orthodox solution, but works.